# Visual Studio 2013 User Defined Literals - Latest CTP

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, user-defined-literals

Microsoft is previewing a new CTP for Visual Studio 2013. [Click here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45508) . How to check if it will have support for C++11 User Defined Literals?

I know that previous versions of VS 2013, including the November CTP did not support UDLs, and VS 2015 will have support for UDLs.

If not in this CTP, is there a possibility that VS will ever support UDLs?

Comment: Care to comment, why the downvote? The same question about UDL has been asked in the past, but not for this upcoming CTP. Oh, wait a minute, did you downvote because I did not add code? That would be funny

Answer (score 0):

You can start from [THIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/08/21/c-11-14-features-in-visual-studio-14-ctp3.aspx) site, there is a lot of links you may find for possible Microsoft Visual Studio CTP updates.